# Why do I get the error "cannot infer type" when using futures::ok?

Tags: rust, future

I know there is `join_all` but it cannot infer type:

```
extern crate futures; // 0.1.25

use futures::future::ok as fut_ok;

fn main() {
    let tasks = vec![fut_ok(1), fut_ok(2), fut_ok(3)];
    println!("{:?}", futures::future::join_all(tasks).wait().unwrap());
}
```

I got this error:

```
let tasks = vec![fut_ok(1), fut_ok(2), fut_ok(3)];
    -----        ^^^^^^ cannot infer type for `E`
    |
    consider giving `tasks` a type
```

Comment: Have you consider to consider giving `tasks` a type ? `let tasks : Vec<FutureResult<_, ()>> = vec![fut_ok(1u32), fut_ok(2), fut_ok(3)];` or `let tasks  = vec![fut_ok::<_, ()>(1), fut_ok(2), fut_ok(3)];`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that any future may in theory return an error. So the `FutureResult` type (which is returned from `fut_ok`) is generic with two type parameters: a type `T` for success and a type `E` for errors.

If this was real code instead of a toy example, you would have some error handling code that would allow the compiler to infer type `E`. In this case you need to specify it, but since you don't use it you can use the empty type `()`. So either of the following should work:

```
let tasks: Vec<FutureResult<_, ()>> = vec![fut_ok(1), fut_ok(2), fut_ok(3)];
```

or

```
let tasks = vec![fut_ok::<_, ()>(1), fut_ok(2), fut_ok(3)];
```

Note that the first is what the compiler means when it says: "consider giving `tasks` a type".

Comment: nice. And how to print the result? `println!("{:?}", futures::future::join_all(tasks).wait()?);`
the trait `std::error::Error` is not implemented for `()`

Answer (score 0):

Full example

```rust
extern crate futures; // 0.1.25
use futures::future::ok as fut_ok;
use futures::future::FutureResult;
fn main() {
    let tasks: Vec<FutureResult<_, ()>> = vec![fut_ok(1), fut_ok(2), fut_ok(3)];
    println!(
        "{:?}",
        futures::future::join_all(tasks).wait().map_err(|_| "Error")
    );
}
```

Prints `Ok([1, 2, 3])`